# Deserializing parts of a serialized whole; Deserializing object contents without deserializing the entire object

Tags: algorithm, serialization

I have an algorithm that requires behavior that I have not previously seen. While traversing a tree that represents a file structure, I want to be able to serialize entire subtrees once they are built (all nodes populated), and store them away to a file or app data for later use.

Hard thing is, I want to build the system in such a way that allows me to deserialize *only* an individual node in the tree structure, without having to deserialize the whole tree that was initially stored away.

For context, the algorithm is intended for my application to use only when I am building file structures of extremely large file systems, with millions of files and directories. The structure becomes so large that it's too costly to keep millions of representative file nodes loaded into memory. I need to be able to store parts or all of the tree away as I go so that I can reduce the memory foot print, however I still need to be able to retrieve information about any part of the tree at any given time, whether it has been serialized and stored away already or not. If at any point I find that a node references another node in the tree structure, I need to be able to do a look up on that node and deserialize or retrieve that already existing node, without having to unpack the whole tree.

This one is hurting my brain.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to structure a file storing a filesystem tree is a list of (path, serialized node data) pairs sorted by the path. You can then lookup a node using binary search. If you want to quickly load all children of a given node, you should use a different key: (number of path components, path, serialized node data). Then all children of a node will be stored in a continuous range of the file.

I haven't tried it myself but it seems that [LevelDB](http://leveldb.org/) implements such a storage.